# Setting proxy in Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium

I am trying to use a proxy in selenium. This is my nodejs code

```
  const chromeOptions = new Options();
  chromeOptions.addArguments(`--proxy-server=http://username-cc-DE:password@someurl:30001`);

  const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
    .build();
  await driver.get("https://google.com");
```

I get an error : `ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`

With curl the request is working, so it's not a username or password problem.

**EDIT:**
If I whitelist my ip address and do not use username and password this works. But this is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with authenticated proxies, maybe using [proxy-chain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxy-chain) might help you :

```js
const proxyChain = require('proxy-chain');

(async() => {
    const oldProxyUrl = 'http://username-cc- 
 DE:password@someurl:30001';
    const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy({ url: oldProxyUrl });

    const chromeOptions = new Options();
    chromeOptions.addArguments(`--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`);
    // rest of your code
})();
```